# Spark Streaming gets stopped without errors after ~1 minute

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

When I make `spark-submit` for the Spart Streaming job, I can see that it's running during approximatelly 1 minute, and then it's stopped with the final status `SUCCEEDED`:

```
16/11/16 18:58:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_XXXX_XXX (state: RUNNING)
16/11/16 18:58:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_XXXX_XXX (state: FINISHED)
```

I don't understand why it gets stopped, while I expect it to run for an undefined time and be triggered by messages received from the Kafka queue. In logs I can see all the `println` outputs, and there are no errors.

This is a short extract from the code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MYTEST")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.setCheckpointDir("~/checkpointDir")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(batch_interval_seconds))

val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

println("Dividing the topic into partitions.")
val inputKafkaTopicMap = inputKafkaTopic.split(",").map((_, kafkaNumThreads)).toMap
val messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, inputKafkaTopicMap).map(_._2)

messages.foreachRDD(msg => {
  msg.foreach(s => {
    if (s != null) {
      //val result = ... processing goes here
      //println(result)
    }
  })
})

// Start the streaming context in the background.
ssc.start()
```

This is my `spark-submit` command:

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 10g --executor-memory 10g --num-executors 2 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC \
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch" --class org.test.StreamingRunner test.jar param1 param2
```

When I open Resource Manager, I see that no job is `RUNNING` and the spark streaming job gets marked as `FINISHED`.

Comment: I would try commenting out `rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)` to get more verbose output. Likely whatever is killing your job isn't tagged `ERROR` so it's being filtered out of the logs. Also, it looks like you are missing your call to `ssc.awaitTermination` at the end of your code.

Comment: @EricM.: Ok, thanks. Let me test it without this line of code. I will tell you the result in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @EricM.:  I tried to run it with `ssc.awaitTermination`, but there was the same problem. But anyway, let me check it as well again.

Comment: @EricM.: You are right. The problem was because of the lack of `ssc.awaitTermination`. I somehow mixed it with `ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout`. Thanks.

Comment: @EricM.: I appreciate if you can publish the answer so that I could accept it. By the way do you know how enable Spark Streaming print-outs in the terminal, so that instead of `Application report for application_XXXX_XXX...` I could see the messages of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a call to `ssc.awaitTermination` to block the driver thread.

Unfortunately there's no easy way to see the printouts from inside your `map` function on the console, since those function calls are happening inside YARN executors. Cloudera Manager provides a decent look at the logs though, and if you really need them collected on the driver you can write to a location in HDFS and then scrape the various logs from there yourself. If the information that you want to track is purely numeric you might also consider using an [Accumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators).